# SQL Проектирование БД с 31 столбцами. (Посещаемость студента)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Доброго времени суток. Суть задания, на C# + MSSQL сделать приложение для работы с посещаемостью студента. В конечном итоге получить таблицу что то вроде этой: [image: Таблица п]

На данный момент надумал две таблицы "Студент" (Id, ФИО) и "Пропуск" (Id, Дата, Студент (Внешний ключ к Студент.Id), Часы прогула)

Но при попытке собрать из этих двух таблиц что то похожее на скриншот выше, столкнулся с дефицитом знаний и решил обратиться к вам.
Из идей есть только одна, в таблице "Пропуск" сделать 31 поле под каждый день месяца, но мне кажется это не правильно.

Comment: Естественно, не правильно

Comment: Исправьте вопрос, проблема не с проектирование, а с объединении таблиц при запросе

Comment: Плюс  таблица (возможно, синтетическая) дат - и тогда всё получится.

Comment: @Akina не нужна таблица дат. Он на C# пишет

Comment: Делайте не колонки, а записи. Т.е. запись состоит буквально из 3х полей: id-студента, дата, и вот та цифра с картинки (2,4). А на экране эти много записей разворачиваете в горизонталь

Comment: У вас классический случай 1:n (один-ко-многим) => нужны 2 таблицы для каждой сущности, и ключ 1-сущности должен быть добавлен в таблицу n-cущности. Вы все правильно сделали. Хранить в таблице количество дней в месяце не нужно, построение ведомости нужно осуществлять программно: берется месяц, вычисляется количество дней в нем, отображаете таблицу месяца, далее запрашиваете из БД по нужному студенту даты пропусков, и отмечаете даты пропусков в соотв.местах.